# How do I sum up the results of multiple bash commands in bash?

Tags: bash, arithmetic

So I've got the following

```
cat a1 | wc -l // term1
cat a2 | wc -l // term2
cat a3 | wc -l // term3
...
cat a10 | wc -l // term10
```

And I'd like to calculate `term1 + term2 + ... + term10` in a one liner (it's fine if it's long). Ideally I'd like to get

```
$(cat a1 | wc -l) + ... $(cat a10 | wc -l)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simpler ways:

```
awk 'END { print NR }' a1 a2 a3 ...
```

or

```
wc -l a1 a2 a3 ... | awk 'END { print $1 } '
```

And, if you have a lot of files, to be sure not to hit the command line length limit:

```
find . -type f -name 'a[123]' -exec awk 'END { print NR }' {} + |
  {
    while read n; do
      tot=$(( tot + n ))
    done
    echo "$tot"
  }
```

If you need to stick to that format (e.g. because you have some complex commands in place of the `cat`s of your examples) you can use [arithmetic expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arithmetic-Expansion.html#Arithmetic-Expansion):

```
echo $(( $(wc -l <a1) + $(wc -l <a2) + $(wc -l <a3) + ... ))
```

or [`bc`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/bc.html), for a wider range of computation options:

```
echo "ibase=10; obase=10; $(wc -l <a1) + $(wc -l <a2) + ..." | bc
```

Answer (score 5):

People say that

```
cat a1 | wc -l
```

is a [UUOC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat) (Useless Use Of Cat), because you could have written just

```
wc -l a1
```

but for your question, you could make it a [useful use](https://www.in-ulm.de/%7Emascheck/various/uuoc/) of cat:

```
cat a1 a2 a3 ... | wc -l
```

This way `wc` sees one file (stream) as the input and prints the total.

Answer (score 0):

`wc` sum it by it self. You can pass all the file at the same time and wc do the sum for you:

```
    wc -l a* | tail -n1
```

Skip the "total" word print by `wc`:

```
wc -l a* | sed '$!d;s/^ *\([0-9]*\) *[a-zA-Z]*/\1/'
```

---

Using a `grep` capable of the `-h` option (such as `GNU grep`) to omit file name for `c`ounting the number of lines `.*` and pipe it to `xargs` and `python` :

```
grep -ch '.*' a* | xargs -0i -- python3 -c 'import sys;print(sum(map(int, sys.argv[2].split())))' _Z_ {}
```

---

The same as above but with only `POSIX` arguments for `grep`:

```
grep -c '.*' a* | xargs -0i -- python3 -c 'import sys;print(sum(map(int, map(lambda x: x.split(":")[1], sys.argv[2].split()))))' _Z_ {}
```

Comment: This is very similar to fra-san's answer, with the drawback of printing "total".